# Android realm filtering not working backwards

Tags: android, filter, realm

I create my query in my fragment and pass it to adapter for later use like this:

```
RealmQuery<Place> query = realm.where(Place.class);
query = query.beginGroup();
if (ids.size() == 0) {
...
} else {
    int j = 0;
    for (RealmInt id : ids) {
        if (j++ > 0) {
            query = query.or();
        }
        query = query.equalTo("id", id.getVal());
    }
}
query = query.endGroup();
query = query.equalTo("loc", loc);
```

in my adapter I filter using this method:

```html
@Override
    public Filter getFilter() {
        final Filter filter = new Filter() {

            @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
            @Override
            protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint, FilterResults results) {
                String text = constraint.toString();
                if (text == null || "".equals(text)) {
                    if(!query.equals(query2)){
                        query = query2;
                    }
                    OrderedRealmCollection<Place> placess = query.findAll();
                    updateData(placess);
                } else {
                    if(!query.equals(query2)){
                        query = query2;
                    }
                    OrderedRealmCollection<Place> placess = query
                            .contains("name", text, Case.INSENSITIVE) // TODO: change field
                            .findAll();
                    updateData(placess);
                }
            }

            @Override
            protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence constraint) {

                FilterResults results = new FilterResults();

                return results;
            }
        };

        return filter;
    }
```

the problem is that when I try to search backwards, that means searching for less characters, list does not update. Why ?

Comment: can you please explain what does "searching for less characters" mean? Maybe some code to show that? Also, "list does not update" which list doesn't update? the `placess`?

Comment: yes, placess does not update, and searching for less characters means that fist I search for "tr" and then I search for "t"

Comment: How do you trigger `filter()` method?

Comment: I do it with edittext onChange listener. But that was not the issue, I dont know why but the query itself was a problem, I modified my code and I create the query every time I use it in filtering, now it works as expected